# Correct way to use state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Update:

So I tried to figure it out, but couldn't. I have an onClick that triggers the `toggleNavbar` function.

I also have the `windowResized` function which checks if the browser is wider than 576. If that condition is true it checks if the `navbarState` is true. If both conditions are true the `toggleNavbar` function should be called from the `windowResized` function.

The issue that I'm having is that the if statement below (the one in the `windowResized` function) never runs, because the state doesn't update.

```js
if (navbarState) {
  toggleNavbar()
}
```

Is there a way to make sure that the navbarState updates before I do the checks?

navbar.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import styles from "./styling/navbar.module.less"

const Navbar = ( props ) => {

  const [navbarState, setNavbarState] = useState(false)
  const [navHeight, setNavHeight] = useState()
  const ref = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    let windowResized = () => {
      let windowWidth = window.innerWidth
      if (windowWidth > 576) {
        if (navbarState) {
          toggleNavbar()
        }
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', windowResized)

    setNavHeight(ref.current.clientHeight)
  }, [])

  let toggleNavbar = () => {
    setNavbarState((navbarState) => !navbarState)
    if (navbarState) {
      props.updateClassNames(styles.contentLeftAnimate)
    }
    else{
      props.updateClassNames(styles.contentRightAnimate)
    }
  }
    
  return (
    <nav ref={ref} id={"navigation-bar"}>
      <div className={`${styles.navLinks} ${navbarState? styles.navActive:""}`} 
      style={{top: `${navHeight}px`}}>
        {props.pages.map((page, index) => (
          <Link key={page.name} className={`${styles.navLink} ${styles.navLinkHoverEffect} ${navbarState? styles.navAnimate:""}`} 
          style={{animationDelay: `${index / 7 + 0.5}s`}} to={page.link}>
              {page.name}
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className={`${styles.burger} ${navbarState? styles.toggle:""}`} onClick={toggleNavbar}>
        <div className={styles.line1}></div>
        <div className={styles.line2}></div>
        <div className={styles.line3}></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: You might want to add the event listener in useEffect and remove the event listener in return function of the effect

Comment: @Pavan Not sure if that is needed when navbar never unmounts

Comment: @Pavan How do I do that exactly. To be honest I'm not even sure what useEffect does. Also what should I remove in the return function. I'm sorry but I'm a noob in React.

Answer (score 0):

You never set navbarState to false again, also put adding event listeners in an effect is better so try this instead:

```
//only set the event listener on mount
useEffect(() => {
  let windowResized = () => {
    let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

    if (windowWidth > 576) {
      // if (navbarState) { this was a stale closure
      setNavbarState(false);
      console.log('Toggle navbar - Width > 576');
    } else {//not sure if you need this else
      console.log('Window is bigger than mobile');
      //set it to true again when it goes over 576 (not sure if you need this)
      setNavbarState(true);
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener('resize', windowResized);
  //probably never happens to layout but if unmounted
  //  remove the event listener
  return () =>
    window.removeEventListener('resize', windowResized);
}, []);
```

The toggle is probably wrong as well if you expect navbarState to immediately change after calling setNavbarState, instead try this

```
setNavbarState((navbarState) => {
  const newState = !navbarState;
  if (newState) {
    props.updateClassNames(styles.contentLeftAnimate);
  } else {
    props.updateClassNames(styles.contentRightAnimate);
  }
  return newState;
});
```

Comment: Doesn't that `setNavbarState((navbarState) => !navbarState)` change the navbarState when the toggleNavbar function is called? Or does it need to be changed in the same function?

Comment: So I tried to figure it out and I couldn't. I updated the question to try and explain better?